# HTML table going out of div

Tags: html, css

I think this is quite simple.

I have this HTML code:

```
<!-- About us --> 

<div id="aboutus">
    <p> About us </p>

    <table class="aboutusTable" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Texto sobre nosotros</p>
            </td>

            <td>
                <img src="img/esquis.jpg">
            </td>   

        </tr>

</div>


<!-- End About us -->
```

And also this CSS code:

```
 #aboutus {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    background: #333;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
   }    

   #aboutus p {
    margin: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color:white;
   }

   #aboutus .aboutusTable {
    margin-top:500px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    float:left;
   }
```

And what I supposed to get from this it should be a table inside the "aboutus" div but what I get is the table at the end of the webpage, even below the footer.

Does anyone know whats happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You put:`margin-top:500px;`.

Try to write: `margin-top:50px;` in the aboutusTable class

Comment: Actually, I was trying to fix it testing with different margins but it was useless. Finally the error was in not including the </table> tag in the HTML code. Anyway, thanks for your help :)